# Вычислить город и континент по IP

Tags: ip, php

Как по IP вычислить город и континент пришедшего на сайт пользователя и записать данные в `date_default_timezone_set('Континент/Его город')`?

Comment: Что вы будете делать, если найдете континент EU и город Ново-Александровка? Какую таймзону будете ставить? 

Лучше, конечно-же, как советует @romeo, спрашивать время/таймзону у клиента, незаметно его ajax-ом пересылать на сервер и там уже хранить/обрабатывать.

Comment: @LiveStreet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @boris_U, если задача сводится к отображению корректного времени, то ajax-запрос ни к чему. DateTime:: W3C, это формат с разницей по времени `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`, т.е. для Москвы: 2015-03-02T03:52:35+03:00. Зная это, тот же [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) сам скорректирует время в соответствии с системным временем клиента. Кроме того, атрибут `datetime` для тега `time` поможет и поисковым движкам.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо отображать дату в соответствии с таймзоной пользователя, то обычно это делают на клиенте. Посмотрите в сторону [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). Кроме того, из коробки будет доступно изменение времени в реальном времени. Вы подобный приём могли видеть в VK, github,... На сервере в таком случае, можно выставить UTC+0, либо любую другую таймзону и выводить дату в `DateTime:: W3C` формате. Атрибут `datetime` тега [time](http://goo.gl/QZsj9B) для этого и нужен.

Для поиска гео-данных по ip на стороне сервера можно воспользоваться [следующими инстрментами](http://goo.gl/mVFuPN).

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить libapache2-mod-geoip - тогда в $_SERVER появятся GEOIP_ADDR, GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE, GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE, GEOIP_CITY

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/

Можно установить расширение php5-geoip, но там при определенных версиях libgeoip и самого php возможны проблемы - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64692